# EF Query Xml Column and Guid Column

Tags: sql-server, xml, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an ASP.Net MVC site using entity framework v6.1.3

A controller needs to query a Sql 2012 table that contains the Guid column "InterchangeId" and the Xml column "Property"

Example content of the "Property" column:

```
<MessageProperties>
    <SPName>
        Waste.CCPAdapter.Receive.CCP
    </SPName>
</MessageProperties>
```

How can I query for a value within the "Property" column using EF? I've tried the following:

```
_context.PipelineRecs.Where(x => x.InterchangeId == interchangeId
                                                    && x.Property.ToString().Contains("the substring I want to find")
                                                    .Single();
```

Comment: What type of column `Property` and entity property `Property` ?

Comment: In Sql Server, Property is an XML datatype. In the entity framework POCO class it is type String.

Comment: Then `XElement.Parse(x.Property)` and use LINQ to XML